# Execute a limited number of Tasks concurrent

Tags: c#, asynchronous, concurrency, task, task-parallel-library

Given I have an `IEnumerable<Func<Task>>` to generate some (crawler)-Tasks which I want to execute concurrent, how can I set an upper bound for the concurrency?

E.g., I do not want that more than 5 of these Tasks are running at the same time. On the other side, there always should be 5 Tasks running if possible.

My current approach is this code:

```
    public static async Task ExecuteConcurrent(IEnumerable<Func<Task>> taskGenerators, int maxDegreeOfConcurrency)
    {
        var executingTasks = new HashSet<Task>();
        foreach (var taskGenerator in taskGenerators) {
            while (executingTasks.Count >= maxDegreeOfConcurrency) {
                executingTasks.Remove(await Task.WhenAny(executingTasks));
            }

            executingTasks.Add(taskGenerator());
        }

        await Task.WhenAll(executingTasks);
    }
```

I am wondering if there is a better method to do this? Maybe, there is already a method available?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like a job for [TPL Dataflow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/dataflow-task-parallel-library)

The advantages are :

1. It work well with `async` and `await` and both *CPU bound* and *IO bound* workloads
2. You can limit concurrency with `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` and many other options
3. You can *Chain* it into more complicated *PipeLines*
4. Works well with *Reactive Extensions*
5. its all built for you by Mr Parallel *Stephen Toub*

[Nuget System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow/)

---

**Very basic example**

```
public static async Task DoWorkLoads(List<IPAddress> addresses)
{
   var options = new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions
                     {
                        MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 50 // limit here
                     };

   var block = new ActionBlock<SomeObject>(MyMethodAsync, options);

   foreach (var ip in addresses)
      block.Post(ip);

   block.Complete();
   await block.Completion;

}

...

public async Task MyMethodAsync(SomeObject obj)
{
    // await something here
}
```

Comment: Cool solution:)! Thanks:)! What if my `IEnumerable` is huge (=bigger than my memory). In this solution the complete `IEnumerable` (if we replace `List<IPAddress>` by `IEnumerable<T>`) would be consumed as soon as possible. Can this be avoided or reduced? Because it would not really be necessary.

Comment: Yeah there is a lot of options, and this is designed for complicated and demanding workloads. Possibly look up Stephen toubs pod cast on tpl dataflow, although they look a bit bgrade he will cover a lot of things I can't on my phone

Comment: @KevinMeier: You'd want to set the `BoundedCapacity` option for that.

Answer (score 1):

Starting from .NET 6, you can use the [`Parallel.ForEachAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreachasync) method:

```
public static Task ExecuteConcurrent(IEnumerable<Func<Task>> taskGenerators,
    int maxDegreeOfConcurrency)
{
    ParallelOptions options = new() { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = maxDegreeOfConcurrency };
    return Parallel.ForEachAsync(taskGenerators, options, (taskFactory, ct) =>
    {
        await taskFactory();
    });
}
```

The `ct` argument is a `CancellationToken` provided by the `Parallel` infrastructure, that will be signaled immediately after a `taskFactory` fails. You could pass this argument to your factory and sprinkle your code with `ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()` in strategic points, to speed-up the termination of the parallel execution in case of an error.